# Update value of pie chart from span on my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, pie-chart

I'm using pie chart script and I'm trying to update value from span on my page.

Pie chart looks like this:

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li><span class="newValue">25</span></li>
  <li>
    <div class='pieCharts'>
      <div class='chart'>
        <div class='percentage' data-percent='100'>
          <span>0</span><sup>%</sup>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$('.percentage').easyPieChart({
  animate: 1000,
  lineWidth: 8,
  barColor: '#00aeef',
  scaleColor: 'transparent',
  onStep: function(value) {
    this.$el.find('span').text(Math.round(value));
  },
  onStop: function(value, to) {
    this.$el.find('span').text(Math.round(to));
  }
});
```

And this is the way I've tried to update **data-percent** value, but it doesn't work:

```
$('.percentage').attr('data-percent', $(this).closest('.newValue').html());
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wtmcc8ny/1/) with full working example

Comment: `$(this).closest('.newValue').html()` is getting evaluated to undefined, which is causing the pie chart to not update. Just changing the value to `$('.newValue').html()` is updating the chart.

Comment: Well I'll be damned. Would you mind posting it as an answer so I can vote you up? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this).closest('.newValue').html()` is getting evaluated to `undefined`, which is causing the pie chart to not update. Just changing the value to `$('.newValue').html()` is updating the chart.

Answer (score 1):

use [data](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

`$('.percentage').data("percent", $('.newValue').html());`

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wtmcc8ny/2/)

or

```
$('.percentage').attr('data-percent', $('.newValue').html());
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wtmcc8ny/3/)

Comment: Thank you for your answers, but that still doesn't update it. I've added JSFiddle with loaded pie chart script so you can see it live

Comment: @DearBee  i was not able to get your jsfiddle yesterday.. i have updated the answer, it was not able to get the closest value of class newValue